# Is it safe to differentiate old and new projects format by the presence of 'Sdk' attribute in Project element?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, csproj

I need to increment NuGet package version each time project is built by TeamCity build server. I use PowerShell for this.

New projects format allows to specify NuGet package information inside the `proj` file. But when there is no such info NuGet defaults to `1.0.0` version, so I need to explicitly create `1.0.buildCount` element, but I don't want to change projects having older format.

Is it safe to use `Sdk` attribute for detecting new format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way would be to detect if the project contains a `TargetFramework` or `TargetFrameworks` (plural) property.

This is currently used inside visual studio to determine which project system to load for C#/VB projects, so even projects importing SDK targets via custom imports instead of using the `Sdk` attribute using the new format need to specify one of these properties in the project file to make it work in VS. See [this project system doc](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/aac52b7c14e637eab02c074f2e81c22692514f83/docs/opening-with-cps.md).

In visual studio 2017 15.6, SDKs can be imported from NuGet regardless of the project using the new or classic csproj format. Only the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDKs are used for the new format.

In addition to the `Sdk=""` attribute on `<Project>` and an SDK can also be referenced using the dedicated `<Sdk>` element or an `Sdk=""` attribute on an `<Import>` element. See [MSBuild's documentation on SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk) for more details.

Note that you don't necessarily have to edit the csproj file, you can also pass `/p:Version=1.2.3` as an argument to all `dotnet` or `msbuild` calls during the build.